# Distinguishing parentheses from brackets

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, I know that there are tuples `(x1,x2,x3)` and also lists `[x1,x2,x3]` and that tuples are not homogeneous and have a fixed length.

On the other hand, lists can be rewritten for example in the form `x1:x2:x3:[]`, which I guess is a function `a ->[a]->[a]`, which makes some sense to me, but in the following code:

```
head' :: [a] -> a  
head' [] = error   
head' (x:_) = x
```

it is unclear to me why we use parentheses, which is to my understanding tuple notation.  It looks more like we should have something like an uncurry function on the colon operator, and take the first input, or something like that.

How are the parentheses behaving here, and why can we not use brackets in some way or another?

Comment: Helpful to note on this topic:

`[x,y,z]` is just sugar for `(x:y:z:[])`

`(x,y)` is just sugar for `((,) x y)`

`(x,y,z)` is just sugar for `((,,) x y z)`

Parentheses are used in pattern matching because usually they are necessary to make sure that, in the case of `(x :xs)`, that this is one pattern for one argument and not a pattern matching three separate args, `x`, `(:)`, and `(xs)`, or some combination, as those could be completely valid arguments to a haskell function by themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parentheses in `head' (x:_)` are just being used for grouping; you can tell no tuples are involved because there are no commas inside.  Without the parentheses, `head' x:_` would be parsed as `(head' x):_`, which doesn't work on the left-hand side of an assignment.

We can't use brackets here because they would require knowing how many elements are in the list passed to `head'`.

Comment: oh, I see. So in general, does Haskell just recognize that on the right side of a colon, some list belongs there?

Comment: @AndresMejia: Yes; `:` is a constructor for lists whose right-hand side is a list.

Comment: `:t (:)` reports `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`.

Answer (score 4):

Parentheses denote tuples when they contain commas. Parentheses without commas are used for grouping, e.g. to distinguish between `x - (y - z)` and `(x - y) - z` or, in this case, between `head' (x:_) = x` and `(head' x) : _ = x`. In other words, all that the parentheses do here is to denote that `:` is being applied to `x` and `_` rather than `head' x` and `_`.

If you used `[]` here, that would be a list pattern. Generally the pattern `[p]` matches if the given value is a list with one element and that element matches the pattern `p`. So `[x:_]` matches a list that contains one element and that element is itself a list matching the pattern `x:_`. Since that's not what you want, you need to use the version without the list pattern.